# почему цикл останавливается когда цифра становится меньше 0 // var i =10 and stop when while (i--)

Tags: javascript

```
var i =10;
// собственно это понятно 

for (i ; i > 0 ; i --) {
 console.log(i);
}

// но можете объяснить тут почему останавливается ? 

for (; i --;) {
 console.log(i);
}

// или тут 

while (i--) {
 console.log(i)
}
```

это  потому что в условиях после 0 значение становится false ?

```
while ( меньше 0 = false)
for (; меньше 0 = false ;)
```

???

Answer (score 4):

Если кратко, то число не равное 0 есть `true`.

Поэтому цикл `for` и `while` в ваших примерах виртуально выглядят так:

```
while (true) {
    // do smth.
}
```

Когда переменная `i` становится равной 0, то неявно идет преобразование, получается `false` и цикл больше не выполняется.

```js
while(0) {
  console.log('я не выполнюсь');
}

console.log('такие дела ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯');
```